# VkViewport negative height?

Tags: vulkan

The validation layer complains:

> vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: pCreateInfos[0].pViewportState->pViewports[0].height is not greater than 0.0. The Vulkan spec states: height must be greater than 0.0
>
> https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkViewport-height-01772

and yet the vulkan spec says in documentation of `VkViewport`:

> The application can specify a negative term for `height`
>
> https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkViewport.html

What am I missing?  These two statements seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use negative height, you need to either enable `VK_KHR_maintenance1` extension, or use Vulkan 1.1+.

Comment: I thought I was using Vulkan 1.1?  I have 1.1.130 SDK installed.  vulkaninfo returns 1.1.130 vulkan version, and 1.1.99 device API version.  Do I need to tell vkCreateInstance something to tell it I want 1.1?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos yes, pass `VK_API_VERSION_1_1` to `VkApplicationInfo.apiVersion `

Comment: Technically, the physical device must support the 1.1 version (via `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`) in this case. That does imply though the `VkApplicationInfo.apiVersion` and Instance version have to be 1.1 too to use it.